# 2012 essentials dasboard shows wrong info

Tags: windows-server-2012

I am running a brand new Dell server with server 2012RT essentials. I find that the "Dasboard" gives wrong information. E.g. in devices it tells me some clients are off line, while for sure they are online and connected. I keep getting warnings that the TSGateway is not running, while it is running. Also Dashboard insists my DNS forward zone is not set to secure updates only, while it is. I have been stopping and restarting services, restarted the whole server a couple of times, but they wrong info in Dasboard doesn't stop.

Does anyone else encountered problems with Dashboard? and more importend, does anyone has a clue on how to solve this?

Thanks,

Ed

Answer (score 1):

On the problematic client, please make sure that services which name includes “Windows Server Essentials” is running, or, you may try to re-start these services and check the result.

On Essentials Server, please open Server Manager – Dashboard, check Events for each server role.

Besides, open Server Manager – Local Server – BEST PRACTICES ANALYZER – Tasks – Start BPA Scan.

Why is My Computer Status Not Showing Online in the SBS Console:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sbs/2009/01/30/why-is-my-computer-status-not-showing-online-in-the-sbs-console/

Best Regards,
Eve Wang